# How do GTA Online discounts stack?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

GTA Online commonly has weekly discounts for products on websites like Legendary Motorsport or Warstock Cache and Carry. Furthermore, some websites also offer a 10% discount if you "stalk" their LifeInvader page.

Say the Rhino tank was 50% off and I still had the LifeInvader discount of 10%. The store page seems to display the price reduced by 50%, but other websites without discounts don't seem to factor in the LifeInvader discount either.

**How, if at all, do these discounts stack? Would I have to pay 0.50 x 0.90 = 45% the original price, or 0.50 - 0.10 = 40% ?**

Comment: Generally when something like this stacks it would be multiplicatively and not additevely as it is essentially doing one after the other not both at the same time (although as you pointed out there is an 'effective' discount which is the result of doing both. 

So if something cost $10, you multiply it by `1-0.5` to get $5 and then multiply by `1-0.1` to get a final price of $4.50. The total discount is  `1-0.5*0.9= 0.55`, which is to say you pay 45% of the original price. 

If it were to work additevely, it would be OP. People with a few discounts could add them to get free stuff

Comment: That being said most of the time companies do not allow multiple discounts/vouchers/etc.